# Powershell outputting string but not executing

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line

Powershell outputs the string instead of executing command.

```
$apps = @()
$apps += Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" # 32 Bit
$apps += Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"  

$apps365 = $apps | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -Match "365" | Sort-Object DisplayName}



$uninPaths = @()
foreach ($item in $apps365) {
    $uninPaths += "& CMD /C "+$item.UninstallString
}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{$uninPaths}
```

Comment: What makes you believe that the uninstall string requires to be run in `cmd.exe`? Usually the unistall string is a standard executable file which often accepts one or more arguments/parameters. They do not need to be exectuted in that specific CLI interface. Why not just try it directly in the PowerShell CLI interface, you're already using?

Answer (score 1):

`$uninPaths` is just a string. To execute it like a command, you can feed it to `Invoke-Expression`:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command $uninPaths
```

`Invoke-Command` is generally used for running powershell commands on remote machines.

Comment: Even with 'Invoke-Expression' it is only outputting the strings but not executing the commands.